# Wrap an element around a sphere in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, adobe-creative-suite

Is there a way to warp an element around a sphere in Illustrator?

Comment: Voting down without explanation is not cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the element into a Symbol, then use the Map Artwork function in the 3D dialog to put it onto the sphere. (This assumes you've created the sphere by revolving a circle. Your question doesn't specify.)

Answer (score 2):

Might be more helpful to give an example of the type of element. In these programs you’ll find there’s more than one way to skin a cat.

[Try this Disco Ball tutorial link:](http://www.vectordiary.com/illustrator/illustrator-disco-ball-tutorial/)

If it isn’t the effect you wish, look up not only WARP tools, but MESH tools as alternatives.